# My JFrame isn't displaying the JLabel with a picture

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Me and a friend are making a game, and well, neither of us know how do GUI. I'm  also inexperienced in Java(amateur C++ programmer), so there's what you're working with here when it comes to my understanding of what I'm doing.

I written code to display a JFrame with a JLabel with an Image. And the code loads fine, but the picture isn't there.

Here is what I got:

```
package game;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Pic extends JFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Pic(){
        JFrame pic = new JFrame("JFrame");
        JLabel player = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon player_icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/res/Untitled.bmp"));
        player.setIcon(player_icon);
        player.setVisible(true);
        player.setSize(100, 100);
        pic.setVisible(true);
        player.setLocation(25, 25);
        pic.setSize(200, 200);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Pic();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This isn't part of the game itself but a test run with a random sprite put in a package named res.
Now my Question: **What did I do wrong to where I can't see my picture, and how can I fix this?**

I would also really appreciate a detailed answer/link that could help with learning GUIs as well as I can't seem to understand some of the older explanations I found on here.

Comment: [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ImageIcon` doesn't support `bmp` file format, it supports `gif`, `jpeg` and `png`

Instead, try using `ImageIO`.  See [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/Untitled.bmp"));
ImageIcon player_icon = new ImageIcon(img);
```

Also, you're not adding the `JLabel` to anything...

```
pic.add(label);
```

Also...

```
player.setVisible(true);
player.setSize(100, 100);
```

Are pointless, Swing components are visible by default and the frame is using a layout manager

It might help to keep [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) book marked.

You will probably also find [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) of some use as well

Comment: +1 for the [supported image types for `ImageIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon(byte[])).

Comment: Thanks for the incompatibility notice on the picture, I also didn't know swing was defaulted to visible.

Comment: @Episha Only the components, windows are invisible by default (and `JInternalFrame`)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Could you point me in the right direction where one would bind input with a chosen image? I would also like to know if it's possible to use coordinates instead of pixels as I faintly remember something referring to that possibility.

Comment: What kind of input?  And no, Swing only works in pixels...Layout managers are different, some work on virtual level, that depends on the individual layout manager

Comment: Mainly keyboard and mouse 1 and 2 input for basic movement of a player and choosing/dragging items out of inventory.

Comment: [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).  There are multiple ways of doing drag'n'drop in Swing, which you choose will depend on your implementation.  For example, you could use the [Transferable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html) API support found in many of the Swing components to transfer the "data" of the components (and not the physical component)...

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to add the jlabel to jframe..

```
pic.add(player);
```

Answer (score 1):

> but the picture isn't there.

I don't see where you add the label to the frame:

```
pic.add( label );
```

> I would also really appreciate a detailed answer/link that could help with learning GUIs

Start with the Swing tutorial. See [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html).

Comment: I feel incredibly dumb... But thanks for the link and the help. I really should look over more.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Ok thanks for pointing that out madprogrammer. Learned something new

On your other question, a good gui tutorial, I found the GUI section of [this book](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/) very helpful

Comment: Not in this case, it means, for each element in the class path, start at there root, otherwise, it would be starting at the package location of the class which is trying to read the resource...

Answer (score 0):

**This can be possible solution !!**

ImageIcon player_icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/res/Untitled.bmp"));

JLabel player = new JLabel(player_icon); //add Image in JLabel

pic.add(player);  // add this label in JFrame